# How can I identify the Annotation/Link location on PDF that iTextSharp finds

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am not sure how to ask my question properly but I will do my best.

We have a logic in place that checks for annotations/links in the document. We have a PDF document that fails that check. However, when we examine this document we find no indication of any link or comment or annotation.

Here is the screenshot of comments/annotation section that indicates that no comment is found.

[image]

However, when we run this document through a C# iTextSharp code, the links do come up, but wihout any specifics

Here is our code where the subtype is returned as 'link' but 'name', 'contents', 'a', 'bs', 'border', 'c', 't', 'h', 'm', 'p', 'rect', 'type' variables return null/nothing. Thus, my question is. How can I find out what exactly is found by the PDF iTextSHarp? What is its location? What is its content? As it is completely invisible and impossible to find on the document

Thank you very much in advance!

```
    public string AnyPDFCheckComments(string inFileName, string strUsername, string strFilename)
    {
            string strCommentType = string.Empty;
            string strWidgetFound = string.Empty;
            string strPageNumber = string.Empty;
            string message = string.Empty;
            string strComments = string.Empty;
            string strCommentsFound = string.Empty;
            int intCommentCount = 0;

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++i)
            {
                strPageNumber = i.ToString();
                if (intCommentCount >= 5)
                {
                    break;
                }

                PdfDictionary pagedic = reader.GetPageN(i);

                PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));

                if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Finding out the comments
                foreach (object annot in annotarray.ArrayList)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annotationDic = null;
                    if (annot is PdfIndirectReference)
                    {
                        annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject((PdfIndirectReference)annot);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        annotationDic = (PdfDictionary) annot;
                    }

                    PdfString name = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
                    PdfString contents = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);

                    PdfString a = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.A);
                    PdfString bs = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.BS);
                    PdfString border = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.BORDER);
                    PdfString c = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.C);
                    PdfString t = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
                    PdfString h = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.H);
                    PdfString m = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.M);
                    PdfString p = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.P);
                    PdfString rect = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.RECT);
                    PdfString type = annotationDic.GetAsString(PdfName.TYPE);

                    **PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);**
                    if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.TEXT)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("text") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "text";
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.FREETEXT)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("freetext") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "freetext";
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.HIGHLIGHT)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("highlight") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "highlight";
                        //break;
                    }
                    **else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.LINK)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("Link") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "Link";
                        //break;
                    }**
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.SQUARE)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("Rectangle-Square") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "Rectangle-Square";
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.FILEATTACHMENT)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("FileAttachment") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "FileAttachment";
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.WIDGET)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("widget") != -1))
                    {
                        strWidgetFound = "widget";
                    }

                    if ((strCommentType != ""))
                    {
                        strCommentsFound = "Yes";
                        intCommentCount = ++intCommentCount;
                        strComments = strComments + "<BR>" + "A comment type of '" + "<b>" + strCommentType + "</b>" + "' has been found on page no: " + "<b>" + strPageNumber + "</b>";
                        if (intCommentCount == 5)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strCommentType = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return strComments;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is our code where the subtype is returned as 'link' but 'name', 'contents', 'a', 'bs', 'border', 'c', 't', 'h', 'm', 'p', 'rect', 'type' variables return null/nothing.

You try to retrieve all those values as strings. But

- the link action 'a' and page 'p' are dictionaries, so are border styles ('bs');
- the 'border', the color 'c', and the rectangle 'rect' are arrays;
- and the highlight mode 'h' and the 'type' are names,

so you won't be able to retrieve them as strings.

Furthermore, 'name' / 't' (**T**) is a form field name and, therefore, not applicable to a link. And 'contents' (in particular for a link) and the the modification date 'm' are optional.

> Thus, my question is. How can I find out what exactly is found by the PDF iTextSHarp? What is its location? What is its content? As it is completely invisible and impossible to find on the document

First of all retrieve the values as their actual type.

Then you get the location from 'rect' which is a required entry. (If 'rect' remains `null`, the annotation is invalid.)

Concerning the content: Annotations don't need to have content, in particular link annotations don't.